# Formatting data in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, format

I have an array incident which is of the following format :-

```
var incident = 
[ [1, ['a', 'b', 'c'] ],
  [2, ['d', 'e'] ],
  [3, ['f', 'g', 'h'] ],
  [4, ['i'] ]
];
```

Now i want to extract data out of this array and format it something like this.

```
data = [ ["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e"], ["f", "g", "h"], "i" ];
```

I tried formatting but no success. 
If anyone could help me out in this. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and check if the element has a length of one for a single element, otherwise return the array.

```js
var incident = [[1, ['a', 'b', 'c']], [2, ['d', 'e']], [3, ['f', 'g', 'h']], [4, ['i']]],
    data = incident.map(function (a) {
        return a[1].length === 1 ? a[1][0] : a[1];
    });

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```